# Get rows with colspan children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I get a reference to all rows (tr's) that have a child cell with a colspan in jQuery?

```
<table id="report">
    <tr>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <!-- Details here -->  
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <!-- Details here -->  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ Look at the attribute selectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this...

```
$('#report td[colspan]').parent();
```

Or this...

```
$('#report tr:has(td[colspan])');
```

Although I'd prefer the first.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$('td[colspan="4"]').parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#report td[colspan]")
```

Use the [Attribute Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector

```
$("#report td[colspan]")
[<td colspan=​"4">​…​</td>​, <td colspan=​"4">​…​</td>​]
```

If you want to search for a td with a specific colspan, you can use

```
$("#report td[colspan='4']")
```

Comment: The first one is actually the [has-attribute-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Comment: @amnotiam ah I hadn't noticed the two as different selectors. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:has()` and the attribute selector:

```
$('tr:has([colspan])');
```